# JDBC - one query to return separate groups of results

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have a table that looks like this: `Col: A (string), B (int), C(string)`

I want to be able to get rows where `A` matches either regex `foo` or regex `bar`. Currently, I perform two queries:

`SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE A LIKE foo` and `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE A LIKE bar`

I am confident that there will be no duplicates between these result sets.

I would like to be able to get an equivalent result by running a single query, so that I don't have to scan the table once for each acceptable value, for example:

`SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE A LIKE foo OR A LIKE bar`

My problem is that such a query produces a result set with all the values jumbled together - I would then need to loop through using my own string comparison to separate the two. Furthermore, strings that match `A LIKE foo` can be very different, so I can't just group on `A`.

Is there a way to perform a single traversal of the table (for efficiency's sake), but still get JDBC / SQL to do the work of separating the results into one group for `A LIKE foo` and another group for `A LIKE bar`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are confident that there would be no duplicates, run a `UNION ALL` with a discriminator:

```
SELECT 'foo' as which_regex, *
FROM myTable
WHERE A LIKE foo
UNION ALL
SELECT 'bar' as which_regex, *
FROM myTable
WHERE A LIKE bar
```

JDBC will run this as a single query, even though it has two parts. There will be an extra "discriminator" column called `which_regex` added to the result, which would contain string `'foo'` or string `'bar'`. You can use this column to decide in what "bucket" to put each row of the result.

Comment: Could you vote to undelete on the `CASE` answer. It's also viable when having more than 2 groups.

Comment: @Kayaman Even though I do like that answer, I am not sure it would be appropriate for me to undelete it, given that the author wanted it deleted.

Comment: @Kayaman and dasblinkenlight - could you describe what that answer was? I didn't see it, but I'd be curious as to what method would be best if I wanted to add an arbitrary number of `OR` clauses

Comment: Also curious - am I correct in assuming I can chain UNION ALL clauses?

Comment: @MyStackRunnethOver Absolutely, you can chain `UNION ALL` as much as you want, as long as the structure of the columns is identical. I made a screenshot of the deleted answer, you can see it [here](http://imgur.com/a/fTITm).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight thank you, that's very helpful. I've never seen this syntax before, do you know why the OP would have reconsidered suggesting it?

Comment: @MyStackRunnethOver My only guess is that it requires repetition of the same condition, which is sub-optimal.

Answer (score 1):

You could add an additional boolean column to the resultset and even sort by that.

```
SELECT A LIKE foo AS group_foo, * FROM myTable WHERE A LIKE foo OR A LIKE bar ORDER BY 1;
```

The first column of the resultset then tells which group it belongs to (true for foo, false for bar) and it's easy to separate them when processing the resultset.